# What after testing the demo?

Tags: jbpm

I'm kind lost

I have tested the demo process. Now I want to start my new own project, but,
should I use the demo installation (with all embedded) and create a new project. Is it recommended?,or I need install the needed (Jboss SA, Drools,etc) from the scratch so I can develop and test.

Sorry for the dummy question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The demo setup is just that, a demo setup, You can use the same setup to build your applications if you want. But there are different ways of creating your applications. You can use your normal way of creating applications and just include the jbpm dependency to your project to start developing your app. Hope it helps.